# Server Partitioner Hangs at 43%

Tags: 10.04, server, partitioning, 64-bit

I bought this server for work (a cheapy): http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=7220575&CatId=2683 to upgrade our WAMP server to a newer LAMP server.

It appears the RAID-5 is actually a [FakeRAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto) which is very unfortunate for me.

Anyway, I'm trying to install a 64-bit 10.04.2 Lucid server from a USB-key and the partitioner seems to hang at 43%. Before the partitioner loads it asks me to "Activate Serial ATA Devices" and I've tried both "yes" and "no".

I did a sha1sum on the ISO and it says it's "OK". I was also able to hit Ctrl+Alt+F2 and run `tail -n 20 /var/log/partman` and saw no error.

What else can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: First of all, I would return the server to the store saying that it is false advertising and it has fakeRAID. This is outrageous, seriously, nothing on there says that.

Comment: I am having this issue with 10.04.3 installing from a USB key. It must be an issue with the installer installing from a USB drive. The FakeRAID is a red-herring here.

Comment: dumb question, but which ISO did you use to make the key?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).